# Responsibility for the asynchronous execution in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, task-parallel-library, coroutine

Who is is responsible for asynchronous data fetching in MVVM? For example, my view has 5 different collections of data to fetch, and I would like this to be retrieved asynchornously in predefined order. For this reason I am using Coroutines and Task.

Question: is VM responsible for this, should my model/repository define GetCustomersAsync method, where it would wrap a query in a Task, or that should be left to VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think the view-model should be responsible for this since this coordinates between the model and view. The model and the repository should be responsible for what they were originally intended for.

Of course the view-model may hand this type of work off to a helper class.